# Efficient way of retrieving all nested objects of a certain type in a complex List

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve objects of a certain type in a List object containing other List objects without having to loop through the entire object tree manually.

I know I can create some kind of loop and check each objects type but I want a more efficient and beautiful way of doing it, like a LINQ statement or some kind of nested lambda expression or whatever other suggestions you might have.

So I have a class object which has a list member, which also has a list member which also has a list member, like so:

- TimesheetType

  - List PeriodType

    - List Entry

      - List WorkDay

And I want to retrieve all objects of type WorkDay.

Here's an example code. I created an example object containing 4 WorkDay objects spread out in the tree. How do I retrieve them efficiently?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class TimesheetType
    {
        public List<PeriodType> PeriodTypes { get; set; }
    }

    public class PeriodType
    {
        public List<Entry> Entrys { get; set; }
    }

    public class Entry
    {
        public List<WorkDay> WorkDays { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkDay
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public double Hours { get; set; }
    }



    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TimesheetType timesheetType = CreateTimesheetTypeExample();

            // Get all WorkDay typed objects in the tree, should return a List<WorkDay> with 4 items in it
            //var allWorkDays = timesheetType.PeriodTypes.Select(...) 
        }

        private static TimesheetType CreateTimesheetTypeExample()
        {
            TimesheetType timesheetType = new TimesheetType
            {
                PeriodTypes = new List<PeriodType>()
                {
                    {
                        new PeriodType()
                    },
                    {
                        new PeriodType()
                    },
                    {
                        new PeriodType()
                    },
                }
            };

            timesheetType.PeriodTypes[0].Entrys = new List<Entry>()
            {
                {
                    new Entry()
                }
            };

            timesheetType.PeriodTypes[1].Entrys = new List<Entry>()
            {
                {
                    new Entry()
                }
            };

            timesheetType.PeriodTypes[2].Entrys = new List<Entry>()
            {
                {
                    new Entry()
                }
            };

            timesheetType.PeriodTypes[0].Entrys[0].WorkDays = new List<WorkDay>(1)
            {
                new WorkDay() { Date = DateTime.Parse("2020-01-01"), Hours = 3 },
                new WorkDay() { Date = DateTime.Parse("2020-01-02"), Hours = 6 }
            };

            timesheetType.PeriodTypes[2].Entrys[0].WorkDays = new List<WorkDay>(1)
            {
                new WorkDay() { Date = DateTime.Parse("2020-01-03"), Hours = 12 },
                new WorkDay() { Date = DateTime.Parse("2020-01-04"), Hours = 24 }
            };

            return timesheetType;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using linq does not make it more efficient by any stretch of the imagination. Convenient? Sure. The loops are happening somewhere anyway, somewhere being Linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `PeriodTypes`, `Entries`, `WorkDays` (so all lists) are never null (but can be empty), couple of `SelectMany` should do the trick:

```
var allWorkDays = timesheetType.PeriodTypes
    .SelectMany(c => c.Entrys)
    .SelectMany(c => c.WorkDays).ToList();
```

`SelectMany` flattens nested list, just what you want to do.

In your example though lists can be null, so you need to filter nulls out:

```
var allWorkDays = timesheetType.PeriodTypes.
    Where(c => c.Entrys != null).SelectMany(c => c.Entrys)
   .Where(c => c.WorkDays != null).SelectMany(c => c.WorkDays)
   .ToList();
```

Or like this:

```
var allWorkDays = timesheetType.PeriodTypes
    .SelectMany(c => c.Entrys ?? new List<Entry>())
    .SelectMany(c => c.WorkDays ?? new List<WorkDay>())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: great! Exactly what I was looking for!